# Animation node set growpoint of instances

Tags: animation-nodes

How how can I set the growpoint of the instances?
It seems to always grow from the center.

Comment: Change the origin point.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

It worked out by applying both SCALE and LOCATION (object) before setting the origin point and the number of instances.